# Display images one below another like tiles in iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to design a screen for my app, where I will download few images from server and display it. All these images should appear in a stack (I don't know the exact term in iOS). All the images must be one below another, and on swiping, the image below it should be visible. How do I design the screen?

How to create a stack of image effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library --> https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards

Or --> https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda

There is no default library for this in iOS, you can use any of the above libraries.

You can even do this yourself, but an existing library gives additional effects.

Comment: Thank you.. I tried using the tinder swipe cards and it worked.